# SharePoint Online - wait time for renamed URL to be available

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have recently changed URL of a site in SharePoint online from

`tenant.sharepoint.com/SiteA` to  `tenant.sharepoint.com/SiteB`

How long will it take for the URL `SiteA` to be available for re-use? We need to create a new site with URL `SiteA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old site URL will become available once we remove the redirect using PowerShell

Use the below script to remove the redirect

```
Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/OldSiteName
```

For more information on Redirects, refer to this [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, changing site URLs in SharePoint Online does not take longer than a minute or two.

Comment: thank you Denis, how long does it take for the old URL to be available for re-use?

Comment: Are SiteA and SiteB subsites of the root site collection?  The name should be available immediately.  If they’re separate site collections, such as /sites/SiteA and /sites/SiteB, then the below answer about removing the redirect will apply

Comment: From my experience, the old URL will never be available again. When you change the site collection's URL, the old URL will still be occupied and will just redirect to the new URL. But you suggest that we can remove the redirect by running a `Remove-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/OldSiteName` command. I didn't know about that part.